# How to get a closed frame when tabuarray has a pagebreak?

Tags: tabularray, frame

I build a framed table with tabularray which looks fine if the whole table is on a single page.

When there is a pagebreak in the table there are open corners.

The open corners disappear when rowhead and rowfoot is used but this adds additional lines (more or less it is a different table) which I do not want in all cases where the table is used.

How can I get a closed frame when tabularray has a pagebreak?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=5mm, bottom=15mm, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{200mm}

\begin{longtblr}[]{
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        rows={3em, m, rowsep=2pt},
        colspec = {X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]},
        hlines = {leftpos = 0, rightpos = 0},
        hline{1} = {1}{-}{leftpos = 1, rightpos = 1},
        hline{1} = {2}{-}{leftpos = 0, rightpos = 0},
        hline{Z} = {1}{-}{leftpos = 0, rightpos = 0},
        hline{Z} = {2}{-}{leftpos = 1, rightpos = 1},
        vlines,
        vline{1} = {1}{-}{ abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
        vline{1} = {2}{-}{ abovepos = 0, belowpos = 0},
        vline{Z} = {1}{-}{ abovepos = 0, belowpos = 0},
        vline{Z} = {2}{-}{ abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
        %rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1
    }
    Alpha &      &       &       \\
          & Beta &       &       \\
          &      & Gamma &       \\
          &      &       & Delta \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, a professional looking tables haven't vertical rules, from horizontal only few of them (around column headers and at end of table) See https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/  ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was not so far away. Thanks Michael for your help!

Work with rowhead and rowfoot which get height 0 assigned + stretch = 0. Add empty headline and footline to the content. Be happy.

```
    ...
    \begin{longtblr}[]{
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        rows={3em, m, rowsep=2pt},
        colspec = {X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]},
        hlines = {leftpos = 0, rightpos = 0},
        hline{1} = {1}{-}{leftpos = 1, rightpos = 1},
        hline{1} = {2}{-}{leftpos = 0, rightpos = 0},
        hline{Z} = {1}{-}{leftpos = 0, rightpos = 0},
        hline{Z} = {2}{-}{leftpos = 1, rightpos = 1},
        vlines,
        vline{1} = {1}{-}{ abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
        vline{1} = {2}{-}{ abovepos = 0, belowpos = 0},
        vline{Z} = {1}{-}{ abovepos = 0, belowpos = 0},
        vline{Z} = {2}{-}{ abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
        row{1}={ht=0pt, rowsep=0pt},
        row{Z}={ht=0pt, rowsep=0pt},
        rowhead = 1,
        rowfoot = 1,
        stretch = 0,
      }
      \\
      Alpha  &      &       &       \\
             & Beta &       &       \\
             &      & Gamma &       \\
             &      &       & Delta \\
      \\
  \end{longtblr}
  ...
```

[image]